# Concatenate Error with TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert

What is wrong with the following code?

```
BULK INSERT test
FROM 'myfile_'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 112) + '.TXT'
    WITH
    (FIRSTROW = 2,
     FIELDTERMINATOR = '~',
     ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

Thanks

Comment: You should post the error you are receiving.

Comment: Just a guess, but have you tried it with the full path?

Comment: Hi John, I know it's an issue with the "+" sign.  Works if I put the full path in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't dynamically concatenate the date to the filename in the bulk insert statement...

If you want to do this, you'll have to build up the statement using dynamic Sql then execute it:

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Sql = 
'BULK INSERT test
FROM ''myfile_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 112) + '.TXT''
    WITH
    (FIRSTROW = 2,
     FIELDTERMINATOR = ''~'',
     ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'')'

EXEC(@Sql)
```

Comment: That fixed it.  Why are we using double "'" to quote \n, ~, and the file name (after the phrase FROM)?

Comment: Two single quotes `''` is the escape character for placing a single quote within a string... if it was just one quote, it would terminate the string.